# How to express this request as a RESTful API?

Tags: api, rest

I am asked to write a small HTTP based service that will accept requests that look like this:

```
[
   { name: 'James Smith', address: '10 Lake Drive' }
   { name: 'Jones', phone_number: '999-123-4567' }
   { name: 'Mr. Lucas', address: 'Detroit, MI' }
]
```

(but with a larger number of requests) and to attempt to determine whether an account exists for each one, returning data that looks like this:

```
[
   { name: 'James Smith', address: '10 Lake Drive', account='123ABC' }
   { name: 'Jones', phone_number: '999-123-4567', account='Not Found' }
   { name: 'Mr. Lucas', address: 'Detroit, MI', account='654CBA' }
]
```

The client of this service (at least, the first client I know about) will use this data synchronously -- it cannot continue until it receives the account numbers back from the service.  (The actual processing done to match up the specifications request items to the accounts is not important.)

I'm asked to provide a RESTful API to this service.  The only way I can see to encapsulate this in a RESTful API is to create the concept of a "LookupRequestDocument" which contains one or more lookup requests.  The client would `POST` this to a URI at `\LookupRequests\`, receive a server-generated URL for the entire request, and then use `GET` to poll that URL until the response is ready.

This feels uncomfortable to me for the following reasons:

1. I've created a new concept (the LookupRequestDocument "resource") solely to allow me to make the API RESTful -- it has no other existence in the problem statement.
2. I've introduced asynchronicity into what is otherwise a synchronous problem.

It seems more natural to me to `POST` the data to a URI like `\DoMatches` and get the completed results in the returned document.  But this does not seem to meet my client's requirement that the API be RESTful.

Question: Is my encapsulation of the problem into a RESTful API the best way of "being RESTful" for this problem?  Is my `\DoMatches` solution actually RESTful even though it does not involve resources as I understand them?

Answer (score 1):

So it seems to that your LookUpRequests process is not RESTful. Its not a stateless transaction, it requires the information in the post to be stored and processed on the server then returned in a different request.

I would do the \DoMatches but are you really "POSTING" anything your "GETTING" information right ? so why wouldn't that be a GET request with the response being the answer/answers ?

Comment: I'm "posting" a request.  I could also see it as a `GET` but then I'd have to encode all the searches into the parameters, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 0):

Neither one is RESTful. This is RPC, pure and simple.

The RESTful approach would be treating each account as a resource, identified by an URI, and checking each one of them on a single request.

If you don't want to have multiple requests like that, you can have a higher level interface as a workaround, where you submit a list of URIs (mimetype text/uri-list) via POST and get a `207 Multi-Status` with the equivalent responses.

Comment: Except that I have no idea of the resource URI I'm after?  Would that be expressed as a `GET` against the collection, expected to return a single URI?

Comment: Could be, filtering the collection by using the values in the payload as query string parameters instead.